# Sending plot image/object in addition to model query result and other variables to Django template

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

Please keep in mind that I am new to Django and web programming in general.

I am trying to do something that seems like it should be simple but I can't figure it out:

I have an 'object viewer' template that I am using to display information about a single selected object from the database and I want to include a graph on the page.

models.py:

```
class MaxExtent(models.Model):

    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    geoName = models.CharField('Geounit name (territories are unique geounits)', max_length=40, null=True)
    sovereignty = models.CharField('Sovereign country name', max_length=32, null=True)
    lakeName = models.CharField('GLWD Lake name', max_length=50)
    areaMax = models.FloatField('Max Extent area (km^2)')
    area2000 = models.FloatField('2000 area (km^2)')
    area2001 = models.FloatField('2001 area (km^2)')
    area2002 = models.FloatField('2002 area (km^2)')
    area2003 = models.FloatField('2003 area (km^2)')
    area2004 = models.FloatField('2004 area (km^2)')
    area2005 = models.FloatField('2005 area (km^2)')
    area2006 = models.FloatField('2006 area (km^2)')
    centerLat = models.FloatField('Latitude of centroid')
    centerLon = models.FloatField('Longitude of centroid')

    poly = models.MultiPolygonField()

    def __str__(self): # default field for string representation

        if self.lakeName:
            return "ID {}: {} ({}, {})".format(self.id, self.lakeName, self.centerLon, self.centerLat)
        else:
            return "ID {}: Not named ({}, {})".format(self.id, self.centerLon, self.centerLat)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render    
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import MaxExtent
from .functions import chart_object_areas

# Object viewer
def objectViewer(request, req_id):
    waterBody = get_object_or_404(MaxExtent, pk = req_id)

    displayFields = [str(f.name) for f in MaxExtent._meta.get_fields()]
    class MaxExtentForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MaxExtent
            fields = displayFields
    fields = MaxExtentForm(instance=waterBody)

    areas = [waterBody.area2000, waterBody.area2001, waterBody.area2002, waterBody.area2003, waterBody.area2004, waterBody.area2005, waterBody.area2006]
    years = [yr for yr in range(2000,2007)]
    # get the bar plot with best fit line on top
    return_chart = chart_object_areas(X = years, Y = areas, waterBody.slope, waterBody.intercept) # UPDATE

    context = {'waterBody': waterBody, 'displayFields': fields, 'chart': return_chart} # UPDATE - tried sending object to template

    return render(request, 'waterExplorer/objectViewer.html', context)
```

I can show the template code but I don't think it would be helpful. Just know it successfully displays attribute information using the waterBody and displayFields, along with a map of the object.

Now for my question...

I am following tutorial [here](http://www.extragravity.com/blog/2014/01/04/matplotlib-django/), which uses matplotlib to create a chart and render it in the template. I am trying to create a simple bar chart using information from the model (area2000 to area2006 as my Y's and year--2000, 2001, ..., 2006 as the X). I have a script that creates this graph based on info retrieved from the model (functions.chart_object_area); currently using matplotlib like in the tutorial. This gets called in views.py and returns the object to be rendered, following example 1 (see [example](http://www.extragravity.com/blog/2014/01/04/matplotlib-django/) and views.py above)

However, how to return f.getValue() in addition to waterBody and displayFields parameters? The tutorial returns the chart like so:

```
    return HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="image/png")
```

But I am returning:

```
    context = {'waterBody': waterBody, 'displayFields': form}
```

So how do I combine the two so I can display the plot in addition to the other stuff I already have?

I am using Django version 1.11

*UPDATE*: I've updated the code in views.py to indicate how I am getting the variables I'm sending to my chart function (see # UPDATE) and am adding the chart_object_areas function here. I also updated in views.py to show that I tried passing the output plot to the template:

functions.py:

```
import sys
from django.http import HttpResponse
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg') # Required to redirect locally
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

import cStringIO

def chart_object_areas(X, Y, slope, intercept):

    plt.ylim(0.0, np.max(Y)+(np.mean(Y)/3))
    plt.xlim(np.min(X)-1, np.max(X)+1)
    plt.ylabel('Area ($km^2$)')
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.bar(X, Y)

    # plot the best fit line too
    fitY = [(slope*x + intercept) for x,d in enumerate(X)]
    plt.plot(X, fitY, color='black')


    plt.savefig('test-plot.png')
    f = cStringIO.StringIO() # redirect per tutorial
    plt.savefig(f, format="png", facecolor=(0.95,0.95,0.95))
    plt.clf()

    return f.getvalue() # per tutorial
```

As you can see, I saved the figure and confirmed that the function *is* producing a plot. However, when I try to render it in the template like so:

```
{{ chart | safe }}
```

Nothing shows up. I am assuming this is because of the way I'm passing to template [in the tutorial, he uses content_type="image/png" when returning the response, and I don't know how to do that as I am sending context to render()].

Again, I am following the tutorial [here](http://www.extragravity.com/blog/2014/01/04/matplotlib-django/) to learn for using matplotlib in Django.